# picture expanding on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like pictures in my gallery to expand into full size after click. I tried everything but nothing really helps. Would be really grateful if someone could help me and explain me how it can be done.

The HTML code and CSS is enclosed. Do I have to create a second version of the image and use `<a href>` to it?

```css
.column {
  flex: 10%;
  max-width: 10%;
  padding: 0 4px;
  margin: 79px;
  ;
}

.holder {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.column img {
  filter: brightness(35%);
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  align-content: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  transition: filter 0.5s;
}

.holder:hover img {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">

    <div class='holder'>
      <img src="/artbook/28.png">
      <p> sample </p>
    </div>

    <div class='holder'>
      <img src="/artbook/24.png">
      <p> sample </p>
    </div>

    <div class='holder'>
      <img src="/artbook/20.png">
      <p> sample </p>
    </div>

    <div class='holder'>
      <img src="/artbook/16.png">
      <p> sample </p>
    </div>

    <div class='holder'>
      <img src="/artbook/12.png">
      <p> sample </p>
    </div>

    <div class='holder'>
      <img src="/artbook/8.png">
      <p> sample </p>
    </div>

    <div class='holder'>
      <img src="/artbook/4.png">
      <p> sample </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please elaborate on what the issue is and what you've tried already to solve the issue. Also, please have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Comment: You're unfortunately asking a question which can become quite complex.  You're asking how to have an image at one size expand to another.  However, I **suspect** you really want something far more robust, that understands the client's screen size and other issues.  Check out [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), the leader in handling mobile & desktop simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really vague, but I tried my best. I would use some overlay utility to make them expand in a new layer. I recomend you jQueryUI and its Dialog utility.
- documentation: http://jqueryui.com/
- about and examples on dialogs: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

I made an example of what I imagine you are looking for. You can see it here:
https://codepen.io/dknacht/pen/dKaONp
It uses an image inside the dialog div and then changes its source according to the source of the image that was clicked.

```
  $("img").click(function (){
    $("#imageDialog").prop("src", $(this).prop("src"))
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
```

Less than 20 lines of code so don't espect so much functionality.
Hope it helps. I stay attend to any doubt.

Comment: hi ! thank you so much however it does not work. I am trying everything possible.

Comment: even tho I edit the script to fit my html and css, it seems like my website just doesn't recognise it. not even the cursor changes when I move it on the picture. what I wanna achieve is basically just moving and zooming the picture in the middle after click and fade out the background of the page.

Comment: The example is working, so I think is a matter of integration. Have you already included the jQuery UI files? Both The js and css?

Comment: Well, I don't know what coup it be. If you want, post some code and I could take a glance.